# ActiveMQ trackMessages property not working

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, logback, failover

I am using ActiveMQ as my JMS system which gets log messages from [JMSQueueAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/net/JMSQueueAppender.html) of logback. The client is a webapp. Both the client and broker are on different machines.

My requirement is that if the client is not able to connect to the broker, then it should store the messages until it reconnects the broker. I tried using failover as mentioned in [Apache Failover Transport Reference](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html). My connection URL is as follows:

```
failover:(tcp://10.17.67.116:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0)?trackMessages=true&maxReconnectDelay=10000&timeout=3000
```

The **trackMessages=true** property is supposed to cache the in-flight messages at the client which will be later delivered to the broker whenever it comes up. Now, my problem is that after the broker comes up, I do not see it getting any messages which were supposed to be delivered.

Where am I going wrong in the configuration of ActiveMQ? This seems to be a fairly simple and straight-forward implementation which is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `trackMessages=true` works only in case of failure i.e. client first connects to server but gets disconnected midway or during send()or before committing the transaction. In that case `failover` protocol should be able to cache few messages (depending upon `maxCacheSize`) and send them to server as soon as it is back.

Try sending say a batch of 100 messages in one transaction and have a delay of say 1 sec in each message send. So message producer will take 100 secs to complete the transaction. Then simultaneously try restarting the server in those 100 secs and see if you it receives those 100 messages.

Refer - http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html